# Cover polygon with rectangles Java

Tags: java, java-2d

I need to cover some polygon with rectangles here's an example :[image]

The black figure in a black square is the polygon that i need to cover with those green rectangles but i need to do it more efficiently that just make a net like i did. Because as you can see there can be place more green rectangles if i moved them.

Rectangles inside are fixed size(just not as big as polygon it self), one for all like in the picture, they can be places vertically and horizontally, i want to fill the polygon as much as it can fit it inside of it, this polygon is just for example, there can be different polygons with holes in them for example that black small square is a hole.

module = rectangle

```
private void coverWithModules(Graphics g, int[] xpoints, int[] ypoints) {
    Polygon module;
    int x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4;
    int moduleRowNumber = 0;
    int totalRows = (getMax(ypoints) / moduleHeight);
    while (moduleRowNumber < totalRows) {
        // first module
        x1 = getMin(xpoints);
        y1 = getMin(ypoints) + distance * moduleRowNumber + moduleHeight
                * moduleRowNumber;
        x2 = x1 + moduleWidth;
        y2 = y1;
        x3 = x1 + moduleWidth;
        y3 = y1 + moduleHeight;
        x4 = x1;
        y4 = y1 + moduleHeight;

        int[] x = { x1, x2, x3, x4 };
        int[] y = { y1, y2, y3, y4 };
        module = new Polygon();
        // check if point are inside the polygon
        checkModulePlacement(g, x, y, module);
        // placing modules in a row
        while (x1 < getMax(xpoints)) {
            x1 = x2 + distance;
            y1 = getMin(ypoints) + distance * moduleRowNumber
                    + moduleHeight * moduleRowNumber;
            x2 = x1 + moduleWidth;
            y2 = y1;
            x3 = x1 + moduleWidth;
            y3 = y1 + moduleHeight;
            x4 = x1;
            y4 = y1 + moduleHeight;
            int[] xx = { x1, x2, x3, x4 };
            int[] yy = { y1, y2, y3, y4 };
            module = new Polygon();
            checkModulePlacement(g, xx, yy, module);
        }
        moduleRowNumber++;
    }
}


private void checkModulePlacement(Graphics g, int[] x, int[] y, Polygon module) {
    boolean pointInside = true;
    boolean pointOnObstraction = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (pointInside) {
            pointInside = roof.contains(x[i], y[i]);
        }
        module.addPoint(x[i], y[i]);
    }
    pointOnObstraction = checkForObstractions(module);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    if (pointInside == true && pointOnObstraction == false ) {
        g.drawPolygon(module);
    }
}
```

I was looking for something and i have found [Something like this](http://www.yzuda.org/download/_CornerStitchingStrips/) maybe there is more stuff like this ?

I don't know where to search for such info. What should i look up to get what i need ? Maybe there is some kind of library for this kind of things ?

Comment: What did you try? Did you put any efforts??

Comment: The picture is what i have made, what is basically just a net that cover the polygon and places rectangles inside of it if they fit. I can put my code here but there is no use because i need a different approach a more efficient algorithm then this.

Comment: The code that you have tried can be more helpful. Post that code

Comment: I would say get the bounds of your polygon. Then put as many squares as you can inside that only putting one if it is contained inside your polygon. That might be a good start at least.

Comment: yeah did it like that but it needs to be more efficient